# JPanel doesnt show up after generated as .jar java

Tags: java

I have a problem with a program i wrote. The Problem is, that when i compile and execute it from my programming environment, everything works and shows up fine, but after i generate a .jar out of it, the frame itself shows up, but the jpanel with icons inside the JTabbedPane doesn't. I used Images in some icons in the jpanel, in other jpanels where i didnt use icons, it works after creating a .jar. i think the problem is getting the icons from the folder where the .jar is in but i dont know how to do this better.

Already tried:

```
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("refresh.png"));
  JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
```

and

```
  URL url = home.class.getResource("refresh.png");
  ImageIcon  icon1 = new ImageIcon(url);
  JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
```

but nothing seems to work after the .jar is cretated

In programming environment:
[image]

As generated .jar:
[image]

I searched everywhere but i didn't find an answer to this. If you need some more code let me know.

Comment: Sorry, you haven't given us enough information about this problem. Please post some code and details on how you create your jar

Comment: Thank you for the answer, gary. I create it with the "create jar" option in my Environment. Its called java editor. There arent any other jar creating options.

Comment: If you are using some automated tool, I suggest that you learn how your create jar button works under the hood.  Or, better yet, you use a tool like gradle or maven to create a reproducible build

Comment: found out the tool that created it wasnt the problem, i edited the question.

Comment: ok, you posted some code.  Is that code working?  is it loading the images? are you getting an exception? null values?  please tell us what is not working specifically.  Where are the image files located?

Comment: well, it compiles without errors or exceptions, so it works but not as it should. i think i'm doing something wrong with importing those .png files. they are located in the same folder as this class and the code is from the attribute part (dont really know what its called, sry), not in any method.

Comment: Try running an example like this one [java resources from classpath](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

Comment: in this example, he reads every string/line from the text file, but how can you cast a file to imageicon? i'm familiar with this type of scanner he used, but i have no idea how to get an icon from this.. thanks btw for your nice try to help me :D (in the classic example)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file from the resources folder like this:

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("refresh.png").getFile());
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.toURI().toURL());
```

This will load the file from your classpath.  For this to work, you will need to copy the file into the standard "resources" directory as shown in [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/).  And yes, you really do want to use this [standard maven convention](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for storing files your application needs.  It simplifies moving your project from development to other environments like test or production.